# Accessing column from update table in subquery in mysql with multiple sets

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update several fields in mysql query and I can't adapt the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839465/accessing-column-from-update-table-in-subquery-in-mysql) to my problem:

```
update m_day md1, 
(select ma.col as ia, mb.col as ib
from m_day md join m_another ma on md.some=ma.some
join m_bother mb on md.someb = md.someb
where md.ID = **md1.ID**) src
set md1.A = src.ia, md1.B = src.ib
where md1.date > '2015-10-10'
```

I get [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'md1.ID' in 'where clause'

The purpose of this query is to add some missing data into md table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting an equality on md1 on the subquery where it is not defined. Do you want to set the md.id=ma.id, instead, or do you want that qualification outside of the parentheses, as follows;

```
update m_day md1, 
(select ma.col as ia, mb.col as ib, ma.id as id
from m_day md join m_another ma on md.some=ma.some
join m_bother mb on md.someb = md.someb) src
set md1.A = src.ia, md1.B = src.ib
where md1.date > '2015-10-10' and src.ID = md1.ID
```

Comment: The "Where"  should act on the inner sql. I though that inner query can know outer query values....

Comment: It can, but this doesn't use an inner query, it uses a select inside of the select statement. The where filters the results, as long as it refers to something named - but in the select statement it doesn't refer to anything named. The problem you have is that you were not referencing anything.